# How to bind datalist in jquery

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, jquery, datalist

I want to bind my datalist in jquery. Here is my client side code:

```
<head>
     <script src="jss/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetProducts",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        });

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            $("[id*=dlOnFrontPageProducts]").attr("border", "1");
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var customers = xml.find("Table1");
            var row = $("[id*=dlOnFrontPageProducts] tr:last-child").clone(true);
            $("[id*=dlOnFrontPageProducts] tr:last-child").remove();
            $.each(customers, function () {
                alert(this);
                var customer = $(this);
                $(".Name", row).html(customer.find("Name").text());
                $(".BrandName", row).html(customer.find("BrandName").text());
                $(".MarketPrice", row).html(customer.find("MarketPrice").text());
                $(".CurrencyShortName", row).html(customer.find("CurrencyShortName").text());
                $(".Price", row).html(customer.find("Price").text());
                $(".WindowImageUrl", row).html(customer.find("WindowImageUrl").text());
                $(".SaleCount", row).html(customer.find("SaleCount").text());
                $(".IsActive", row).html(customer.find("IsActive").text());
                $("[id*=dlOnFrontPageProducts]").append(row);
                row = $("[id*=dlOnFrontPageProducts] tr:last-child").clone(true);
            });
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dlOnFrontPageProducts" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
        RepeatLayout="Table" EnableTheming="True" OnItemDataBound="dlChanceProducts_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="box-product fixed">
                <div class="prod_hold">
                    <a class="wrap_link" href="ProductDetail.aspx?prid=<%# Eval("ProductId") %>"><span
                        class="images">
                        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgWindow" /></span> </a>
                    <div class="pricetag_small">
                        <span class="old_price">
                            <%# Eval("MarketPrice")%><%# Eval("CurrencyShortName")%></span> <span class="new_price">
                                <%# Eval("Price", "{0:n}")%>
                                <%# Eval("CurrencyShortName")%></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <h3>
                            <%# Eval("Name") %></h3>
                        <p>
                            <%# Eval("BrandName")%></p>
                        <a class="add_to_cart_small" href="/core/ajaxresult.aspx?act=prod&prid=<%#Eval("ProductId")%>">
                            Sepete Ekle</a> <a class="wishlist_small" href="#">Listeme Ekle</a> <a class="compare_small"
                                href="#">Karşılaştır</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</body>
```

My returned data is correct but datalist doesn't bind. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: When you say that the datalist doesn't bind, do you mean that your Ajax callback doesn't update the generated HTML on the client side?  Or do you mean that some server side code that's supposed to generate the DataList *on the server* isn't working?

Comment: What is your openion...? will it work on javascript? if can you please explain how?

Answer (score 0):

here is my code pls check with your code and make appropriate changes and get answer

### Asp.Net Code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlCustomers" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns="3"
                            CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="3" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="1" style="width: 310px; height: 100px; border: thin 2px #428bca; color: black; background-color: #EEEEEE">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align: center; background-color: cyan; color: black">
                                            <b><span class="plot"><%# Eval("PlotNumber") %> </span></b>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Seasoncode:<span class="Season"><%# Eval("Seasoncode") %> </span>
                                            <br />
                                            Village: <span class="Village"><%# Eval("Village") %></span><br />
                                            Planting Date: <span class="PlantingDate"><%# Eval("PlantingDate")%></span><br />
                                            Plant: <span class="Planttype"><%# Eval("Planttype")%></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            Crop: <span class="CropType"><%# Eval("CropType")%></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            Nursery: <span class="NurseryType"><%# Eval("NurseryType")%></span><br />
                                            Cutas Setts: <span class="CutasSetts"><%# Eval("CutasSetts")%></span><br />
                                            Seed Supply: <span class="SeedSupply"><%# Eval("SeedSupply")%></span><br />
                                            Cutas Bulk: <span class="CutasBulk"><%# Eval("CutasBulk")%></span><br />
                                            Cane Supply: <span class="CaneSupply"><%# Eval("CaneSupply")%></span><br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:DataList>
```

**Jquery code:-**

---

```
function plot_details(paramstr) {
            $("[id*=dlCustomers]").hide();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CommonView.aspx/GetCustomers",
                data: "{'paramstr': '" + paramstr + "', 'procname': '" + 'DBSP_Get_PartyPlotView' + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var customers = xml.find("Table");
            var repeatColumns = parseInt("<%=dlCustomers.RepeatColumns == 0 ? 1 : dlCustomers.RepeatColumns %>");
            var rowCount = Math.ceil(customers.length / repeatColumns);
            var i = 0;

            while (i < repeatColumns * rowCount) {
                var row = $("[id*=dlCustomers] tr").eq(0).clone(true);
                for (var j = 0; j < repeatColumns; j++) {
                    var customer = $(customers[i]);
                    if (customer.length == 0) {
                        $("table:last", row).remove();
                    } else {
                        $(".plot", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("PlotNumber").text());
                        $(".Season", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("Seasoncode").text());
                        $(".Village", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("Village").text());
                        $(".PlantingDate", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("PlantingDate").text());
                        $(".Planttype", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("Planttype").text());
                        $(".CropType", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("CropType").text());

                        $(".NurseryType", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("NurseryType").text());
                        $(".Variety", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("Variety").text());
                        $(".CutasSetts", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("CutasSetts").text());
                        $(".CutasBulk", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("CutasBulk").text());
                        $(".SeedSupply", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("SeedSupply").text());
                        $(".CaneSupply", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("CaneSupply").text());
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                $("[id*=dlCustomers]").append(row);
            }
            $("[id*=dlCustomers] tr").eq(0).remove();
            $("[id*=dlCustomers]").show();
        }
```

Comment: If he/she has to find answer by her/him self then why would he/she post here, if you have a solution then mention only that part with explanation.

Comment: you won't give solution and won't allow solution provider, this question was asked 4 years ago and 1848 times viewed there is no clear solution when i found and give one solution, you can't accept means i just remember this golden words                                                        I Respect Blind People Because
They Judge Others By Their Behaviour Not By Their Looks

Comment: Don't get angry, read my comment again which contains word "explanation", it means you've to explain what changes needed to be done to solve that problem and that's it. It will help others to understand what the problem was and how you solved that problem.

Comment: i'm cool budy,i mentioned here is my code pls check with your code and make appropriate changes and get answer, that  means they have compare my code and their code, if they compare means they can get answer otherwise they have to copy paste my code then they change slightly means they can get answer, so simple only