# Binding asp.net datalist with jQuery is not working

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I saw several posts regarding this topc. I noticed one code. I also worked on the same code n the below code url . 
[**Binding asp.net datalist with jQuery**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677249/how-to-bind-datalist-in-jquery)

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
            $("[id*=dlOnFrontPageProducts]").attr("border", "1");
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var customers = xml.find("Table1");
            var row = $("[id*=dlOnFrontPageProducts] tr:last-child").clone(true);
            $("[id*=dlOnFrontPageProducts] tr:last-child").remove();
            $.each(customers, function () {
                alert(this);
                var customer = $(this);
                $(".Name", row).html(customer.find("Name").text());
                $(".BrandName", row).html(customer.find("BrandName").text());
                $(".MarketPrice", row).html(customer.find("MarketPrice").text());
                $(".CurrencyShortName", row).html(customer.find("CurrencyShortName").text());
                $(".Price", row).html(customer.find("Price").text());
                $(".WindowImageUrl", row).html(customer.find("WindowImageUrl").text());
                $(".SaleCount", row).html(customer.find("SaleCount").text());
                $(".IsActive", row).html(customer.find("IsActive").text());
                $("[id*=dlOnFrontPageProducts]").append(row);
                row = $("[id*=dlOnFrontPageProducts] tr:last-child").clone(true);
            });
        }




<asp:DataList    ID="DataList1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Names="Arial"
Font-Size="10pt" RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor = "White">
    <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lbldescription"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description")%>'>
         </asp:Label>
     <asp:Label ID="name"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>'>
        </asp:Label>                   
   </ItemTemplate>
```

How can I bind using ajax and jquery. My page takes 16 seconds to load the page. That's y i am going for jquery.

Please help me for finding solution....

Thanks

Comment: How much data is being binded to the drop down list ?

Comment: almost 500 rows. I want to bind to datalst. and the datalist is well formated...

Comment: I am using datalst as <asp:DataList    ID="DataList1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Names="Arial"
    Font-Size="10pt" RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor = "White">
 
          

           <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lbldescription"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description")%>'></asp:Label>
                           <asp:Label ID="name"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>'></asp:Label>
                            
           </ItemTemplate>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to `Bind` a `DataList` control via jQuery because the control is only created when bound through server side code, e.g. on the code behind.

If you are wanting to use Ajax and jQuery to `bind` controls, then you would be better of using plain old HTML.

Alternatively, bind the `DataList` with some data so that it is rendered, and then the HTML elements will be created on the page and you can work with them.

Comment: "Alternatively, bind the DataList with some data so that it is rendered, and then the HTML elements will be created on the page and you can work with them"

Comment: How it is possible using html elements...? can you provide me any sample codes...?

Comment: Was going to post an example but got side tracked.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this concept without postback using callback methods. the code is given below

```
 Dim callback As String = ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(Me, "message", "processMyResult", "context")
        Dim script As String = "function CallBack(message,context){" + callback + ";}"
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "CB", script:=script, addScriptTags:=True)



 Public Sub RaiseCallbackEvent(ByVal eventArgument As String) Implements System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler.RaiseCallbackEvent
    If (eventArgument) Is Nothing Then

        returnValue = "-1"

    Else

        binddata(eventArgument)
    End If



    Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    Dim sw As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter(sb)
    Dim hw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    gvCustomers.RenderControl(hw)
    returnValue = sb.ToString()

End Sub

Public Function GetCallbackResult() _
As String Implements _
System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler.GetCallbackResult

    Return returnValue

End Function

Public Function binddata(ByVal eventArgument As String) as nullable
    Dim adp As New dsRegistrationTableAdapters.searchPackagesTableAdapter()
    Dim dt As New dsRegistration.searchPackagesDataTable()
    dt = adp.GetData(eventArgument, StartDateTextBox.Text, EndDateTextBox.Text)


    gvCustomers.DataSource = dt
    gvCustomers.DataBind()
    SearchTextBox.Focus()


End Function
```

thanks all for your help....